# Server and Client in C using a Message Queue (no socket code)

Tags: c, server, pthreads, client, ipc

I am trying to implement threading, a binary semaphore, and message queues in a client and server program. Everything works, except for the reply in my server to send a response back to the client. When I uncomment the reply, the server loops infinitely after receiving a message.

They both use a message.h header file that is a struct containing:
contents (character), id(int), and mtype(int).

// server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include "message.h"


int sqid, cqid, pid;
msg m, n;
sem_t sem_var;
key_t key;


void requestSem();
void setSem();
void unlockSem();
void reply();
void readQueue();
void listener(void *ptr);


int main() {

    key = ftok(".", 'z');
    sqid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0600);

    if(sqid < 0) {
        perror("Error creating the message queue.\n");
}

pthread_t thread1;
pthread_t thread2;
pthread_t thread3;

char *msg1 = "Thread 1";
char *msg2 = "Thread 2";
char *msg3 = "Thread 3";

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void *) &listener, (void *) msg1);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void *) &listener, (void *) msg2);
pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, (void *) &listener, (void *) msg3);

pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
pthread_join(thread3, NULL);

}

// always listen for messages

void listener(void *ptr) {

while (1) {

requestSem();
setSem();
readQueue();
unlockSem();
//reply();

    }
}

void readQueue()
{

// print the proccess ID and thread ID

printf("Process ID: %d, Thread ID: %d\n", getpid(), pthread_self());

// receive message

if(msgrcv(sqid,&m,sizeof(struct msg),0,0) < 0) {
    perror("Error receiving a message.\n");
}
printf("Message was received...\n");
fprintf(stderr, "The contents are: %s\n", &m.contents);
fprintf(stderr, "The client's ID is: %d\n", (&m)->id);
fprintf(stderr, "The thread's ID is: %d\n", pthread_self());

}




void requestSem()
{
// request semaphore (lock)

sem_init(&sem_var, 1, 1);

printf("Semaphore requested.\n");

}

void setSem()
{
// lock semaphore

sem_wait(&sem_var);

printf("Semaphore set.\n");

}

void unlockSem()
{
// unlock semaphore

sem_post(&sem_var);

printf("Semaphore unlocked.\n");
}

void reply()
{
// send reply

printf("got here\n");

pid = (&m)->id;

cqid = msgget(pid, 0600);

n.contents = (&m)->contents;
n.mtype = 0;
n.id = getpid();

if(msgsnd(cqid, &n,sizeof(struct msg),0) < 0) {
    perror("Msg send error");
}

msgctl(sqid,IPC_RMID,NULL);

}
```

// client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#include "message.h"



int main() {

// initialize variables

int mqid, rqid;
msg m;
key_t key;

// initialize message

int pid;
pid = getpid();
m.id = pid;
m.mtype = 1;

// create message queue and response queue

key = ftok(".", 'z');
mqid = msgget(key, 0600);
rqid = msgget(pid, IPC_CREAT | 0600);

if(mqid < 0) {
    perror("Error creating the message queue.\n");
}

if (rqid < 0)
{
    perror("Error creating the message queue.\n");
}

// loop forever, can send as many messages as you want

while(1) {

fprintf(stderr, "The ID of the client is: %d\n", pid);

// prompt for user input

printf("Enter one character to send: \n");
scanf("%s", &m.contents);

// send message

if(msgsnd(mqid, &m,sizeof(struct msg), 1) < 0) {
    perror("Error sending the message.");
}

//msgctl(mqid,IPC_RMID,NULL);

printf("Message was sent successfully!\n");

// receive response

printf("Waiting for a reply...\n");

if(msgrcv(rqid,&m,sizeof(msg), 0, 0) < 0)
{
    perror("Error receiving a message.\n");
}

printf("Message was received.\n");
fprintf(stderr, "The contents are: %s\n", &m.contents);

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help. Everything functions as it's supposed to when reply is commented out within listener in the server. Uncommenting it creates an infinite loop.

Comment: this sequence of statements: `if(msgsnd(mqid, &m,sizeof(struct msg), 1) < 0) {
    perror("Error sending the message.");
}

printf("Message was sent successfully!\n")` along with several others are not correct.  In this case, outputtin a message saying an operation failed, then immediately outputting a message saying the operation was successful.. Suggest reading the man page for perror() and related statements.

Comment: For readability by us humans, Please consistently indent the code.  Suggest indent after EVERY opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: Why is the contents of a received message being passed to `stderr` rather than `stdout`?

Comment: these lines: `printf("Enter one character to send: \n");
        scanf("%s", &m.contents);` have a problem in that the prompt requests one char, but the '%s" format specifier requests multiple characters.  Perhaps you meant: scanf( "%c", &m.contents );    And should always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: The client.c code implements a 'forever' loop, so this program will never exit.   Is that what you want?

Comment: It is 'almost' always a bad idea to #include header files that are not used in the code.   So this statement: `#include <errno.h>` should be removed

Comment: when calling an output function, such as `fprintf()`  there is no need to get an address, unless you are planning on outputting the address.  The posted code fails to define the typedef `msg` nor the underlying struct definition. but, the `contents` field is set/read like it is a single char.   For these and other reasons, these two lines: `fprintf(stderr, "The contents are: %s\n", &m.contents);
fprintf(stderr, "The client's ID is: %d\n", (&m)->id);` are not correct

Comment: This line: `fprintf(stderr, "The thread's ID is: %d\n", pthread_self());` has a an incorrect format specifier for the returned value from `pthread_self()`,   You could perhaps correct the problem by casting the returned type to `(int)`.   Strongly suggest, when compiling, to always enable all the warnings and fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: When calling `scanf()`, with a '%s' format specifier, always use a 'max length' modifier so the user cannot overrun the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

the reason the server never exits is because each thread has a

```
while(1)
```

loop and no way to exit that loop